# Не получается объединить сети

Tags: windows, сеть, ip, маршрутизация

Прошу прощения за возможный оффтоп, но может кто-нибудь поможет мне с объединением 2-х сетей. Сам программист, вопросы сетевого администрирования знаю лишь поверхностно.

---

**Суть:**
Есть предприятие, в нём 2 локальные сети: 192.168.0.0 и 192.168.1.0. Каждая существует по отдельности. Имеется ПК с двумя сетевыми адаптерами (192.168.0.240 и 192.168.1.240), который подключён к обеим сетям, под управлением Windows 7.
Нужно, чтобы через этот ПК один ПК из сети 192.168.1.0 с ip 192.168.1.2 имел доступ к ПК из сети 192.168.0.0 c ip 192.168.0.2.
Я объединил интерфейсы 192.168.0-1.240 в мост, и назначил мосту 2 ip адреса: 192.168.0.240 и 192.168.1.240. Прописал на **всех** ПК маршруты

```
route add -p 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.240
route add -p 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.240
```

В результате с ПК с мостом пингуются все ПК, а с ПК в сетях пингуются адреса как 192.168.0.240, так и 192.168.1.240 (с обоих ПК оба адреса), но вот друг-друга они (192.168.0.2 <=> 192.168.1.2) не видят.
В чём может быть проблем? Спасибо.

---

Ранее мне уже доводилось решать задачу объединения сетей, и мост на windows работал прекрасно.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы компьютер стал маршрутизатором, надо включить IP Forwarding в настройках драйвера. На винде это делается в ключе реестра `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`, значение `IPEnableRouter`. Правда, так написано в инструкции к WinXP, лично я не проверял достаточно ли этой настройки.

А вот в мост вы интерфейсы объединили зря. Мост и маршрутизация по-хорошему являются взаимоисключающими: мост объединяет две сети на канальном уровне, а маршрутизация - на сетевом.

---

Альтернативный вариант - оставьте мост и объедините подсети. К примеру, назначьте в обоих сегментах адреса из подсети 192.168.0.0 либо оставьте как есть - но назначьте маску подсети 255.255.254.0. Маршруты в таком режиме не нужны.

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. На одном канале может сидеть сколь угодно сетей и соответственно маршрутизаторов. Они же на разных уровнях работают, как Вы верно подметили. Просто этот мост явно лишнее

Answer (score -2):

Согласен с Павлом, поставьте маску перекрывающую обе сети если используете бридж.
Если хотите полноценную маршрутизацию, то установите какой-нибудь софт поддерживающий програмный маршрутизатор типа Usergate или Traffpro, их очень много.

Comment: Чем вам винда из коробки не полноценная? Usergate - это шлюз, для простой маршрутизации он избыточен.

Comment: ответ на первый вопрос - всем. Это не маршрутизатор, и спорить безсмысслено. Даже в Unix надо ставить дополнительные паеты как правило для полноценной работы в качестве роутера. Я лишь привел пример возможных программ, а не вкоем случе не настаиваю на его использовании, тем более что он платный.

Comment: Что в linux, что в freebsd, что на винде для того чтобы использовать их в качестве маршрутизатора по фиксированной таблице маршрутов, достаточно сделать ровно одну вещь: включить ip forwarding.